# React: Convert timestamps in list of objects from Node.js server and save to state

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, typescript

My question is regarding how to:

1. Map through incoming fetch data array of objects
2. Extract the timestamp property in each these objects, when these objects where created
3. Convert these timestamps to `new Date(item.timestamp).toLocaleString()` or similar [image]
4. Store these new converted timestamps inside of the 'original' array of objects
5. And finally store this array inside of the item state

The code below gives me this:
[image]

This is what I have so far:

```
    import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
    import { Link } from "react-router-dom";

    interface PostListProps {}

    interface PostListState {
      id: number;
      heading: string;
      text: string;
      timestamp: number | string;
    }

    const PostList: React.FC<PostListProps> = () => {
      useEffect(() => {
        fetchItems();
      }, []);

      const [items, setItems] = useState<PostListState[]>([]);

      const fetchItems = async () => {
        try {
          const data = await fetch("http://localhost:3001/api/posts");
          const items = await data.json();
          const timestamps = items.map((item: any) => {
            return {
              timestamp: new Date(item.timestamp).toLocaleString()
            };
          });

          console.log("Before items is sent to state", timestamps);

          setItems([
            ...items,
            {
              timestamp: timestamps
            }
          ]);
          console.log("Right after items been sent to state", items);
        } catch (error) {
          console.error(error);
        }
      };

      return (
        <>
          {items.map(item => (
            <div key={item.id}>
              <h1>
                <Link to={`/posts/${item.id}`}>{item.heading}</Link>
              </h1>
              <p>{item.text}</p>
            </div>
          ))}
        </>
      );
    };

    export default PostList;
```

This is my mock-server in Node.js

```
const posts = [
  {
    id: 1,
    heading: "post 1",
    text: "This is a blogpost",
    timestamp: ""
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    heading: "post 2",
    text: "This is also blogpost",
    timestamp: ""
  }
];

app.get("/api/posts", (req, res) => {
  res.send(posts);
});

app.post("/api/posts", (req, res) => {
  const timestamp = Date.now();
  req.body.timestamp = timestamp;

  const post = {
    id: posts.length + 1,
    heading: req.body.heading,
    text: req.body.text,
    timestamp: timestamp
  };
  posts.push(post);
  res.send(post);
});

const port = process.env.PORT || 3001;
app.listen(port, () => console.log(`Listening on port ${port}...`));
```

Am I thinking about this the right way? Should I do this right before I save the array to state or could I do it right before I render the timestamps?

Feel free to ask if there are anything that I need to clarify.

Thank you beforehand,

Erik

Answer (score 0):

Friend of the React and TypeScript communities here...

A few thoughts come to mind here:

1. Can you do the timestamp conversion on your server? `const timestamp = new Date().toLocaleString()`
2. Personally, I wouldn't store the `{ timestamp: timestamps }` in the same piece of state as `items`. Seems like it would be better to keep that separate because they're different shapes and this object is not the same as an "item".
3. If you can't do the timestamp conversion on your server, it seems like it might be better to do the timestamp conversion when you render the `item` rather than when you `fetchItems`.

```js
const PostList: React.FC<PostListProps> = () => {
  // ...

  return (
    <>
      {items.map(item => (
        <div key={item.id}>
          <h1>
            <Link to={`/posts/${item.id}`}>{item.heading}</Link>
          </h1>
          <p>{item.text}</p>
          <p>{new Date(item.timestamp).toLocaleString()}</p>
        </div>
      ))}
    </>
  )
}
```

Obviously, a lot of this is really a design choice. But hopefully this helps share some additional non-biased thoughts on how you might approach this. Hope this helps!

Joe